# javascript создание модели данных

Tags: javascript

Вопрос общий, о том как правильно делать.

В С# или Java  я создаю модели для манипулирования данных.
Например:

```
class Post
{
    public int id;
    public string title;
}
```

Тут же я могу задать дефолтные значения, и всегда знаю какие есть поля.

В js тоже есть классы, но мне не понятно как организовывать их структуру в проекте,  и правильный ли это подход?

Пример проблемы:

Я получаю с сервера json такого вида

```
[
  {
    id:0,
    arr:['1','2']
  },
  {
    id:1,
  }
]
```

Теперь если я сделаю скажем так:

```
data[1].arr[0]//undefined
```

то я получу ошибку. Ее не было бы если бы была модель которая описывать получаемые данные с дефолтными значениями.

Вопрос: как правильно решать такую проблему в js? Если классами, то как организовать проект(выносить каждый класс в отельный файл? А потом импортировать где нужно?). Может как то помочь в этом вопросе typescript?

Answer (score 2):

### 1. вашу проблему можно решить со стороны сервера

> Я получаю с сервера json такого вида

### 2. а можно со стороны клиента

если **не нужна** проверка типов то проще сделать так:

```js
const user = {
    login: null,
    password: null,
    age: null,
    avatar: null,
}

let serverResponce = {
    user: {
        login: 'qwa',
        avatar: 'htttp://',
    }
}

let nUser = Object.assign({}, user, serverResponce.user)
console.log(nUser)
//{login: "qwa", password: null, age: null, avatar: "htttp://"}
```

### 3. TypeScript

считается что TypeScript С#'ам ближе чем JS'ам и если не пугает:

> © Чего на самом деле не хватает? Нормального pattern matching-а, ну и иногда тоска накатывает из-за отсутствия typesafety. Но в такие моменты я обычно вспоминаю def myFunc[A, B >: C, E:A, D / E](a: A, b:B, c:C, d;D, e: E): [A / E] и как-то легче становится :)

смотри
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html
ключевые слова `reflect-metadata` `@validate`

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    }
}
```

ещё ссылок

- https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm
- https://github.com/typeorm/typescript-example
- https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers

---

и не забываем, что любая проверка типов это небольшая, но работа (не хочу писать замедление)

---

UPD: ещё можно поискать что-либо на тему JSON валидации, но это выглядит более фантастично, чем проброс типов в JS из TS

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Smth {
  constructor(info) {
    this.id = info.id;
    this.arr = info.arr || [];
  }
}

var data = [{
  id:0,
  arr:['1','2']
},{
  id:1,
}];

data = data.map(x => new Smth(x));

console.log(data[1].arr.length);
```

Comment: А по структуре проекта? выносить все классы в отдельные файлы и потом импортировать?

Comment: @user282446, как удобно, так и делай.